# my screen is broken on my droid razr micro so is there any other way to turn it off or restart it without using the touchscreen?

Tags: motorola-droid-razr, broken-screen

That's really all there is to it. My screen is not working well enough that it will show the graphics, so I have no way of using it. I'm hoping that maybe it'll start working again if I can restart it.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the power button for some long time (~10 seconds should be enough).
It will then shutdown or restart (depends on the kernel configuration) and do a hard reboot (this is not bad, it just means that it doesn't use some weird quick boot technique on boot)

This should fix temporary issues with your phone. If not, then you need to check what is broken and maybe replace/repair it or get a new phone.